# Getting rid of non-restrictive clause in the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, clauses

I try to understand if there a better way to structure the following sentence:

> Note that if `min-width` is greater than `width` or `max-width`, it overrides them, both.
>
> ```
> // results to 300 px
> width: 100px; max-width: 200px; min-width: 300px;
>
> // results to 200 px
> width: 100px; max-width: 300px; min-width: 200px;
>
> // results to 200 px
> width: 100px; min-width: 200px;
>
> // results to 200 px
> max-width: 100px; min-width: 200px;
> ```

I don't like this non-restrictive "both" in the end of sentence, it sounds cumbersome.

On the other hand, I cannot simply remove the comma before it, because removing that comma will make the meaning less clear: it won't be clear whether I want to stress *overriding **both** properties* or *overriding* at all.

Does the first sentence sounds good for native speakers? How can I make it really neat and concise?

Maybe this is required to add the word *either*, and then removing the comma won't make the meaning unclear?

> Note that if `min-width` is greater than **either** `width` or `max-width`, it overrides them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite clear without the comma.  It means it overrides both properties.

I don't understand what you think is being stressed by inserting a comma.  I know that the pause that the comma implies seems unnatural, as if "both" is an afterthought.

Adding "either" is possible. It does highlight the idea that there are two options. However, it doesn't really change the meaning.

Comment: My concern is that without a comma, the sentence could be understood in the following way: _If ..., it overrides them both. Otherwise, it overrides only one of them (that is, only `width` or only `max-width`)._

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a possible interpretation.   Pragmatically if it is less than both how would you know which it overrides?  What does "override" even mean if a value is less?  So there is no way it could be understood like that.